# TCL + Expect Windows 8 64-bit

Tags: tcl, expect, telnet

I want to use TCL with Expect at my Windows 8 64-bit OS
I've installed 32-bit version of TCL from ActiveState, installed Expect via teacup, and use 32-bit version of plink (cause native Windows Telnet client doesnt work).
Testing scripts actully work, but they print no output to console, just run silently.

Here is example

```
package require Expect
log_user 1
spawn plink -telnet -P 2001 10.10.10.100
send "conf t\r"
send "hostname yyyy\r"
send "int loo100\r"
send "int loo101\r"
send "int loo102\r"
send "exit\r"
```

If i run it directly from shell command by command i receive just some number after spawn. Please, look at screenshot.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

What is the problem ?
Tnkx

Comment: I think it is more normal to put an `expect` statement before each `send`. Checks that things are happening as expected…

Comment: I am sure, that telnet session happened and even command were sent and applied correctly.
I think that i should receive some input right after "spawn", but i see just random number every time, like 3528 at screenshot

Comment: `spawn` will return the process id. Unless you expect for a pattern, you will never witness the program's output via `Expect`. Try adding the expect for the device's prompt after sending each commands.

Comment: i tried to expect device's prompt, but no luck at all.
expect cant recognize it and waits till timeout i believe

Comment: Did you find a fix for this ? i'd be interested, having exactly the same issue. Win 10 64bit, Expect 32bit in tcl script, i can spawn a process, but it reads nothing, then times out.